# How to loop through multidimensional array without getting outOfBounds error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

How can i make the for loop only go through one sublist of the multidimensional char array without getting the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

```
char[][] letters = {
    {'a','e','i','o','u','l','n','s','t','r'},
    {'d','g'},
    {'b','c','m','p'},
    {'f','h','v','w','y'},
    {'k'},
    {'j','x','q','z'}
};

for(int i= 0; i < letters[0].length; i ++)
{
    System.out.println(letters[1][i]);
}
```

Comment: You have a 2d array. Try it with a nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the values of the **second** sublist with this, because index starts at 0. And since the second sublist has only 2 items, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown at the third iteration

change it to this and it will work:

```
System.out.println(letters[0][i]);
```

Edit: from your comment I understood that you want to do the same not only for the first sublist but for any of them. The important thing here is that at both mentions of `letter[x]` x must be the same. So you can use a variable for that.

```
int sublistIndex = 0; // choose any index  (0-based) to define which sublist
char[][] letters = {{'a','e','i','o','u','l','n','s','t','r'},{'d','g'},
       {'b','c','m','p'},{'f','h','v','w','y'},{'k'},{'j','x','q','z'}};
for(int i= 0; i < letters[sublistIndex].length; i ++)
{
   System.out.println(letters[sublistIndex][i]);
}
```

Comment: I want it to be so if i change the System.out.println(letters[1][i]);, and say change the number to a 2. The number in letters[0].length will change too

Comment: @CodeTurn Do you want to make one loop for all items and sub-items in this array?

Comment: @Cashbee Thanks for the help!